# Batch insert in Hive using Hive-JDBC

Tags: hive

I am trying to insert data into Hive (NON-ACID) table using hive-jdbc connection. It works if I execute a single SQL query in a 'statement'. If I try to batch the SQL using 'addBatch', I get an error 'method not supported'. I am using hive-jdbc 2.1 and HDP 2.3. Is there a way to batch multiple SQL into a single 'statement' using hive-jdbc?

Answer (score 2):

As Ben mentioned, the `addBatch()` method is not supported in hive jdbc.
You can insert multiple data in one statement, for example:

```java
String batchInsertSql = "insert into name_age values (?,?),(?,?)";
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(batchInsertSql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, "tom");
preparedStatement.setInt(2, 10);
preparedStatement.setString(3, "sam");
preparedStatement.setInt(4, 20);
preparedStatement.execute();
```

Comment: Is there any better way to solve this problem? It's so slow.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is just an interface for method addBatch from Hive-JDBC, there is NO implementation ...

```
public void addBatch() throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    throw new SQLException("Method not supported");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, works for me:

```
INSERT INTO <table_name> VALUES ("Hello", "World"), ("This", "works"), ("Be", "Awesome")
```

This will run as one map-reduce job, hence will save time as well.
It will create three rows with the mentioned values.

Use `StringBuilder` to loop over the values and keep appending to the query String, and then execute that String.